# Interaction of GIT using sambashare (SMB) on MAC is very slow

Tags: git, macos, web-deployment, samba, smb

I am using GIT to develope a webapplication running on a MS-Server. As I don't want to work on the server directly I mounted the `wwwroot` Directory as a sambashare. There, I cloned an instance of my webapplication for developement.
Every time I want to do a `git diff` or `git status` it takes seconds to process.

This makes it almost impossible to use graphical interfaces for GIT, as each time any action is performed the repository status is refreshed and the program stops working for several seconds.

Here is the configuration I use:

- GIT: `git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`
- OS: MacOS X Mountain Lion
- Samba: ?? The man-page of smb-util has a time signature of February 14, 2000

Is there a way to either accelerate the performance of GIT? Or is there a simple way to work on the local filesystem and propagate the changes to the webapplication without committing/pulling the repository?